# I'm having trouble updating the file in PHP

Tags: php, file, upload

I can upload files with the same codes on a different page. But when I use this code to update the image file, the file can only be in jpeg format! I get the error. Where am I making a mistake?

The table also has multiple columns. I just want to update the 'foto' column.

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="text" name="idi" value="<?PHP echo $cikti['id']; ?>">
<input type="file" name="resim" multiple="multiple"/></input><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="dosya" value="Change Image..." /></input>
</form>



<?php

if($_POST['idi']){
$degisecek_urun_id = $_POST['idi'];
if ($_FILES["resim"]["size"]<1024*1024){
if ($_FILES["resim"]["type"]=="image/jpg"){
$dosya_adi = $_FILES["resim"]["name"];

        $uret=array("as","rt","ty","yu","fg");
        $uzanti=substr($dosya_adi,-4,4);
        $sayi_tut=rand(1,10000000); 
        $yeni_adi="images/".$uret[rand(0,4)].$sayi_tut.$uzanti;
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resim"]["tmp_name"],$yeni_adi)){
            echo 'The file was uploaded successfully.';

        $sonuc = $db->exec("UPDATE urun_bilgileri SET foto = $yeni_adi WHERE id = $degisecek_urun_id");


       if ($sonuc){
        echo 'Saved to database.';

        }else{
            echo 'An error occurred while recording!';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Failed to upload file!';
    }
}else{
       echo 'The file can only be in jpeg format!';
}
}else{          
    echo 'The file size cannot exceed 1 Mb!';
}


}

?>
```

Comment: When you say *I get the error* - what does it say and does it indicate any line number?

Comment: do I print the error code?

Comment: If something is displayed to show an error then please add it to your question.

Comment: only, Notice: session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in /home/akayecza/public_html/ana_header.php on line 40

Comment: You should look into using prepared statements fro SQL, but your problem may be that when including character fields in your SQL, you need to have quotes round the vlaue - `foto = '$yeni_adi'`

Comment: $sonuc = $db->exec("UPDATE urun_bilgileri SET foto = '$yeni_adi' WHERE id = '$degisecek_urun_id'"); or  $sonuc = $db->exec("UPDATE urun_bilgileri SET foto = '$yeni_adi' WHERE id = $degisecek_urun_id");   not working

Answer (score 0):

On line no. 4 edit

```
    if ($_FILES["resim"]["type"]=="image/jpg")
```

Replace it with

```
    if ($_FILES["resim"]["type"]=="image/*")
```

Comment: I got the same mistake. When I try to cancel the image format and try to upload the file, but this time the database is in error in the registration code.

Comment: You are getting error message because you are only allowing jpg images to be uploaded and not other extensions.

Comment: I'm already just uploading files in jpg format. The file I'm trying to load is in the jpg extension.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: degisecek_urun_id in /home/akayecza/public_html/urun_duzenle.php on line 275

Comment: Where is $cikti_id coming from ?

Comment: The file was uploaded successfully. An error occurred while recording!

Comment: see that if($_POST['idi']) change it into if(isset($_POST['dosya']))

Comment: I get $ cikti_id from this database on this page.

Comment: Write print_r($cikti_id) somewhere and check if you are getting the desired ID ?

Comment: or echo $cikti_id somewhere on that page to check if it is getting the value or not !!

Comment: print_r ($ cikti ['id']); I can see what is needed. Printing on the screen.

Comment: Write this to see the error actually.... $sonuc = $db->exec("UPDATE urun_bilgileri SET foto = $yeni_adi WHERE id = $degisecek_urun_id") or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));

Comment: File uploaded successfully. Array ( [0] => 42S22 [1] => 1054 [2] => Unknown column 'images' in 'field list' )

Comment: change $yeni_adi="images/".$uret[rand(0,4)].$sayi_tut.$uzanti; to $yeni_adi="images/".$dosya_adi; to check if it works or not.

Comment: $sonuc = $db->exec("UPDATE urun_bilgileri SET foto = '$yeni_adi' WHERE id = $degisecek_urun_id") or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));         $yeni_adi this time the quotes worked smoothly. I still don't understand what the problem was. In the meantime, 'if ($ _FILES ["image"] ["type"] == "image / jpg")' I've canceled the query.

Comment: Now write it like $yeni_adi="images/".$uret[rand(0,4)].'-'.$sayi_tut.'-'.$dosya_adi; ... see if it works

Comment: If I delete the file format query, it works fine my code

Comment: if you dont need only jpg images then you can set the format to  image/* , it will allow all extensions